# Meaning of returns char when return value is void, and gets an void argument?

Tags: c

I am learning about threading with C, and I'm a bit confused about the example given. They declared a function `print_name` with return value of `void`, but then it returns a string — how and why? The function `print_name` accepts one argument which is called `name` but it is a pointer of `void`; what does a variable of type `void` mean, and how can it accept a string?

***main.c***

```c
#include <stdio.h> // I-O
#include <pthread.h> // threading

void *print_name(void *name)
{
    puts(name);

    return name;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, print_name, "ha ones be eilat");

    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

***To compile and run with `gcc`***

```
$ cc main.c -o main -Wall -pthread && ./main
ha ones be eilat
```

Comment: it is not `void` but **`void *`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument type and return type is not `void` but *pointer to `void`*.

In C both argument passing and returning a value with the return statement happen as if by assignment. `void *` is a generic pointer type and conversions to and from `void *` from and to other pointer types will happen implicitly, i.e. without a *cast*.

The character literal which is an array of `char` decays to `char *` and is implicitly converted to `void *` to match the prototype of `pthread_create`. The `void *` is implicitly converted to `char *` to match the prototype of `puts`.

`print_name` has prototype `void * print_name(void *)` so that a pointer to that *function* will match the type expected by `pthread_create` (The third parameter is `void *(*start_routine) (void *)`.)

The declaration of `pthread_create` is

```
int pthread_create(
    pthread_t *thread,
    const pthread_attr_t *attr,
    void *(*start_routine) (void *), 
    void *arg
);
```

Comment: Oh, *converted to void * to match the prototype of pthread_create*. Now I understand, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The type `void *` is a 'universal pointer' that can point to any object type.  (On many, but not all, machines, a `void *` can also hold a function pointer — however, that's tangential to this question.)  In C, any object pointer can be converted to a `void *` and back to the original type without change.  Using `void *` can be dangerous; it can be extremely useful (and thread creation can show both dangerousness and usefulness).

Contrary to the claim in the question, the function `print_name()` is defined to return a `void *` value as well as accept a `void *` argument.  The [`pthread_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html) function expects a (pointer to a) thread function that matches the signature:

```
void *thread_function(void *);
```

And that's what is passed to it.  Since the function returns a `void *`, it is legitimate to return the pointer it was passed, though that is actually an unusual thing to do.

The return value from the thread function can be collected by passing an appropriate, non-NULL pointer to `pthread_join()`; the example does not demonstrate that.

```
void *result;
if (pthread_join(thread_id, &result) == 0)
    printf("Result: <<%s>>\n", result);
```

This would, in the example, print `Result: <<ha ones be eilat>>` on a line.  Many times, you'd convert the returned pointer to an explicit non-`void` pointer — e.g. `char *str = result;` — and then use that.

Note that there is nothing in C that would stop you calling:

```
int i = 0;
if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, print_name, &i) != 0)
    …thread creation failed…
```

The wrong type of data is passed, but that will be treated as OK by the compiler.  At run-time, if you're (un)lucky, an empty line will be printed, but anything is possible (because of undefined behaviour) as you passed an `int *` to a function that requires a `char *` to work correctly.  This inability to check types is a weakness of `void *`, but it is also a strength as it allows the `pthread_create()` function to pass a pointer to any type of data to a function.  The onus is on the programmer to get the types right — the called function must expect to convert the `void *` parameter to a pointer to the type that was really passed.  Also, the data passed via the pointer to the function needs to be stable — not changed if another thread is started.  There is no guarantee about the order in which threads will read the data passed.  Passing a pointer to a structure and changing the value in the structure between calls to `pthread_create()` is a no-no.  Similarly with the return value.  There are some additional wrinkles there.  The data pointed at must be valid after the function exits, so it can't be a local variable.